AccessControlException: Access Denied ("java.net.Permission" "getProxySelector") Java Class with okhttp3 library in lotus notes
i'm developing a Java class in and IBM Lotus Domino app, it uses the okhttp3 library :
import java.io.*;
import okhttp3.*;

public class Uploader { 
    public String Poster(String FileName, String sId) 
    {
        // Declarations
        String httpResult = "";
      
        // Create OkHttp client
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        System.out.println("OkHttpClient");
        
        // Create multipart request body
        RequestBody requestBody;
        System.out.println("RequestBody");
        //
        ...
        return httpResult;
    }
}

got the error :
enter image description here
Java error:java.security.AccessControlExceptions: Access Denied
("java.net.NetPermission" "getProxySelector")
i add the line : permission java.net.NetPermission "getProxySelector";
in the "C:\Program Files\IBM\Lotus\Domino\jvm\lib\security\java.policy" file
but no success, any ideas?
Thanks in advance
Lea
i'm trying to use the okhtt3 library in a Java class into Lotus Notes

Run it with -Djava.security.debug=access,failure to see what policy was in effect at the point of failure. Clearly not the file you changed.

hi, thanks, i'm not running a JAR file from Lotus Notes, i'm running a JAVA code within Notes, so i'don't know how to set -Djava.security.debug=access,failure into Domino Server configuration / JVM Domino server configuration,

Did you restart the Domino server after changing the config file?

hi Richard, yes i did, thanks
